# When generating a random payment id, why doesn't the integrated address also change in the receive tab in the gui wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, payment-id, integrated-address

Doesn't the payment id get integrated into the monero address during generation? I click on generate and the integrated address stays the same. Also how can one generate a new monero address? Or do we just stick with just one? There isn't an option in the gui to generate a new address.

I'm trying to integrate this into my ecommerce site and I need to be able to generate a new address or payment id for each customer.

Comment: If it doesn't change, this is a bug, and the right place for this is https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/issues

Comment: actually it does change. the change is seen at the last 10 characters of the address. the first set of the address is the same for any generated paymented id.

Comment: Good, then that is expected indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address looks like its not changing because the first part of the address is the same for all integrated addresses. Its only the last part of the address shows the unique payment id add on.